# Nested loop to access each record index

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

I have a text file that has 4 records and each record consists of 4 values. I also have 3D matrix where each item in this matrix is one of those records. I want to iterate over this matrix and get for each item its record index from the text file.

Here is a simple example of what the data looks like:

```
float res[4][3][4] = {
    {{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}, {4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7}, {7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 0.0}},
    {{4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7}, {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}, {7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 0.0}},
    {{7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 0.0}, {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}, {4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7}},
    {{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4},{5.5, 1.1, 4.4, 6.6}, {4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7}}
};

float records[4][4] = {
    {7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 0.0},
    {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4},
    {4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7},
    {5.5, 1.1, 4.4, 6.6}
};
```

I want the output to be:

```
results[4][3]= {
    {2, 3, 1},
    {3, 2, 1},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 4, 3}
}
```

I implemented this code:

```
int *rowIndices = (int *)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int rowIndex = -1; // Initialize to -1 if no matching row is found
    printf("Results for record %d:\n", i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        int match = 1; // Assume a match
        printf("Residue %d: ", j + 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            printf("res %f: ", res[i][j][k]);
            printf("record %f: ", records[j][k]);
            if (res[i][j][k] != records[j][k]) {
                match = 0; // Not a match
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) {
            printf("%d ", j);
            rowIndices[i] = j;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Row index for res[%d]: %d\n", i, rowIndices[i]);
}
```

Inside the third loop when it compares the first value of `res` and first value `record` and they don't match it automatically goes for the next `res` and next `record`. I want it to compare each `res` with all records and get its index because it must be there.

Comment: If you know you have `4` rows, why are you using dynamic allocation instead of a plain array for `rowIndices`? And how is `n` related to the number of rows? What is the actual value of `n`? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: And it seems you misunderstand something about array sizes. In the array definitions you show, you consistently use `3` as the size, even when the size is `4`. Typo in the question? Or in your actual code? Again, please create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: Thank you so much , yes you are right i did fixed them , i only was trying to give an example because in the reality i have high dimension.